# Tomcat creates new database session on every start + mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat7

I am developing a web application and my stack is Mysql+ hibernate+ spring. I noticed that each time i start my tomcat a new database session is created.

my application.context xml has the following configuration

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="15" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
    </bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possibilities.

1. Either your application is executing queries on start up. This can be verified by turning on hibernate/spring logging.
2. The default minIdle/initialSize connection property of the connection pool is 1. Initial size refers to the initial number of connections created when the pool is started while minIdle refers minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being created

Comment: Hi,I checked my spirng logging. I couldnt see any query execution. I tried changing my min idle to 2 and still I could see a new database session on every start of Tomcat

Comment: What happens when you set the initialSize to 0?

Comment: Even i set initalSize 0 it creates a new db session every time I start my tomcat

Comment: How do you know that a new db session is created? from a database query?

Comment: Also for troubleshooting I would recommend you to decorate your dbcp.BasicDataSource and debug the getConnection() to see who is trying to create the connection. The stacktrace can be captured and that can help in understanding the initial connection creation root cause.